# std::list resize giving unexpected results

Tags: c++

I am just learning and have a likely dumb question.

I have 2 containers, one is a vector and one is a list. They are both filled with the ints 1,2,3,4. After they are initialized I resize the container to a size of seven, then print the contents of the container.

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <vector>     
#include <list>

int main () 
{
std::list<int> lst= {1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};

lst.resize(7);
vec.resize(7);

for (auto p = lst.begin(); p!=lst.end(); ++p)
  std::cout<<"List: "<<*p<<std::endl;

for (auto p = vec.begin(); p!=vec.end(); ++p)
  std::cout<<"Vector: "<<*p<<std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

In the output I am getting:

```
List: 1
List: 2
List: 3
List: 4
List: 0
List: 1994995248
List: 0
Vector: 1
Vector: 2
Vector: 3
Vector: 4
Vector: 0
Vector: 0
Vector: 0
```

Do I have to explicitly tell the list that I am adding 0s to avoid this?

Comment: What compiler are you using? I seems to not able to reproduce it here:http://ideone.com/9BwQJ6. They are supposed to be value initialized if you do not specify the value when you resize.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/resize/

Comment: Well, actually it seems it should use default value to fill the spots, but you can try to call `lst.resize(7, 0);`, just to see what would happen.

Comment: MinGW GCC 4.6.2. resize(7,0) works.

Comment: What compiler options are you passing?

Comment: I can confirm this on Mingw gcc 4.6.3 compiled with `g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic test.cpp -o test.exe`. After list resize, the extra elements have some random value. Building the same code with Clang 3.2 works as expected.

Comment: looks like bug in implementaions

Comment: Compiling it as: g++ test.cpp -Wall -std=c++0x -o test.exe

Comment: This is a good reason to not use MinGW.  You should be able to trust something as basic as resizing a container with a default value.

Comment: @JasonL No, `int()` (which is not a default-constructor, but a value-initialized, i.e. zero-initialized, value) should result in `0`. `int a` is not the same as `int a()` (which doesn't even work) or `int a = int()` (which is the same as `int a = 0`). If the compiler gets this wrong, than it fails at a concept so basic to make it outright useless.

Comment: @ChristianRau: If that is your attitude toward compilers then what do you use? No compiler in existence meets your strict standard.

Comment: @ZanLynx It's true that compilers have many bugs. But it isn't that this (proper value initalization of `int`s and other fundamental types) is something rarely ever needed or totally abstract. This is a very fundamental feature of the language, whose failure is bound to result in trouble with a whole many applications. It doesn't need to meet *"my strict standard"*, but it surely should get the most basic things right before one can do something useful with it. (Beware, I'm not talking about just the failure of the list constructor, but the failure of `int() == 0` in the first place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users posted, `lst.resize(7,0)` will solve your problem. Using `lst.resize(7)` and leaving off the initialization value tells the compiler that it doesn't matter what the value is (presumably because you're going to set it later). This allows the operating system to leave whatever random value is sitting in the memory, rather than spending resources on changing it.

The `Vector` container, on the other hand, includes code that automatically initializes your items to zero.

Comment: I thought the standard required for the other elements of the list to be initialized to `0` too

Comment: This however is not in line with the C++ standard, which requires the new elements to be value-initialized (and thus zero-initialized for `int`s).

Comment: In a typical implementation `resize` has two parameters with the second one having a value-initialized default argument. For this reason `lst.resize(7)` is equivalent to `lst.resize(7, 0)` and is guaranteed to initialize new elements with zeros. Other implementations can do it differently (overloading etc), but the end result must be the same.

Comment: @AndreyT *"Other implementations can do it differently (overloading etc)"* - Actually this is more of a question which standard the implementation follows. The C++03 standard explicitly stated a single function with a value-initialized default argument, while C++11 turned this into two separate functions. But nevertheless, as you say, all standards always required value-initialization for the one-argument call.

Comment: @Christian Rau: That's not entirely accurate with regard to C++03. In 17.4.4.4/2 C++03 explicitly permitted implementations to replace default arguments with overloads, i.e. C++03 implementations were already offered the choice of implementing two versions of `resize` instead of one with default argument (do it "C++11 style"). This is exactly why the changes made by C++11 do not formally qualify as "breaking". And this is exactly why I said "in a *typical* implementation..." in my comment. This permission is also present in C++98.

Comment: @AndreyT *"In 17.4.4.4/2 C++03 explicitly permitted implementations to replace default arguments with overloads"* - Oh, nice to know, thank you.